# Angular test with `async` causing Jasmine timeout?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

I recently upgraded a project to Angular 6, and now tests that were working fine before are now failing. Here's an example of one of those tests:

```
  beforeEach(
    async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [CampaignsDetailScheduleComponent],
        imports: [
          SomeModule,
          ReactiveFormsModule,
          TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: TranslateFakeLoader }
          }),
          StoreModule.forRoot({})
        ],
        providers: [{ provide: ConfigService, useValue: ConfigServiceMock }],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
      });
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CampaignsDetailScheduleComponent);
      comp = fixture.componentInstance; // Component test instance
      _store = fixture.debugElement.injector.get<Store<State>>(Store);
      comp.campaignModel$ = of(CampaignMockData);
      fixture.detectChanges();
    })
  );

it(
    'close edit schedule modal',
    async(() => {
      spyOn(_store, 'dispatch');
      comp.onClose();
      const args = new ShowHideEditScheduleModal(false);
      expect(_store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(args);
    })
  );
```

Pre-Angular 6, this test passed with no issues. But now under Angular 6, I get the error:

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.--Pendng async tasks are: [type: macroTask, source: setInterval, args: {handleId:4072,isPeriodic:true,delay:0,args:[object Arguments],__creationTrace__:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]},type: macroTask, source: setInterval, args: {handleId:4075,isPeriodic:true,delay:0,args:[object Arguments],__creationTrace__:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]}]
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: I do not know if this is some Jasmine thing, but are you sure you need the `async` since you don't have any `await` ?

Comment: @Seblor In this case, `async` isn't the JavaScript `async` keyword, it's a helper function provided by Angular.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do you have any link to the doc about that ?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://alligator.io/angular/testing-async-fakeasync/

Comment: Have you tried this fix ? https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4697#issuecomment-364631869

Comment: These aren't protractor tests, they're just plain old Jasmine tests.

Comment: The Angular Material docs suggest using TestHarnesses: https://material.angular.io/guide/using-component-harnesses, but I still get Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)

Answer (score 1):

use `fakeAsync` instead of `async` in before each block.

Answer (score 0):

You can either increase the default jasmine timeout (which is 5s) interval by doing

```
it(
    'close edit schedule modal',
    async(() => {
      spyOn(_store, 'dispatch');
      comp.onClose();
      const args = new ShowHideEditScheduleModal(false);
      expect(_store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(args);
   // increase default timeout interval to 10s
}), 10000);
```

OR you can solve it using `done()` method. Adding this will wait for your test to complete. I guess you cannot use `async` while using `done()`

```
it('close edit schedule modal', (done) => {
          spyOn(_store, 'dispatch');
          comp.onClose();
          const args = new ShowHideEditScheduleModal(false);
          expect(_store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(args);
          done();
       // increase default timeout interval to 10s
 }, 10000);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Unfortunately neither of these solutions seem to work in this case. :(

Comment: Ok `comp.onClose();` is executed asynchronously right. Then you can simply add the code inside `setTimeout()`. Or if you wish to stick with `async` then use `fixture.whenStable().then()`

Comment: What's really strange is that I have other tests in other files that follow the same pattern, and those tests are passing. I have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: How does `onClose()` look like? Can you add that to your code?

Comment: I was able to narrow down the problem. If I comment out the call to `fixture.detectChanges()` in the `beforeEach` call, the test passes. Not sure why, though...

Comment: Well then, you probably have something asynchronous inside `ngOnInit()`. Since you commented out `fixture.detectChanges`, your `ngOnInit()` was not invoked and hence your test case executed synchronously which made it pass.