# Angular 4 Jasmine issue with compileComponents

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

We have a legacy Angular 4 project using SystemJS. We have been asked to implement unit test cases using Jasmine and Karma. I started writing a test suite for one component. It looks something like this (pseudo code below):

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
         TestBed.configureTestingModule(
                    imports,
                    providers,
                    declarations etc.
                ).compileComponents();
    }));
```

Now if I just add a simple dummy test case to this suite, it fails with the error:

> async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by
>   jasmine.default_timeout_interval

If I remove the call to compileComponents, it starts working.
On the other hand, if I use a very basic component with no providers and child components, the setup works. So I am guessing that the various imports/providers are causing it to break somehow.

Has anyone faced such an issue before?

The reason I need compileComponents is that we are using templateUrls and not inline HTMLs in our components.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular test with \`async\` causing Jasmine timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50747446/angular-test-with-async-causing-jasmine-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need "async" to configure testing modules?

```
beforeEach(() => {
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     imports: [],
     declarations: [],
     providers: []
 });
 const fixture = TestBed.createComponent({{componentName}});
 fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Comment: I need to initialize the application by calling some services (even if they are Mock), such as Reference data, user information etc. Hence async. In your code you have not used compileComponents, is it not required?

Comment: No It is not required. Normally I write two types of test: 1) for template and 2) for component.
Only for template `detectChanges` is used.
Also `configureTestingModule` takes care of resolving all dependencies so I am still not sure what other dependencies you are talking about...

Comment: The dependencies are basically some state that I need to initialize and then expose via services. This state is used across the application (user ID, user role, etc.). Is there a way I can get access to my global service instance. If so then I can invoke a method on it to initialize it.

Comment: Just to clarify...you are writing `unit test` for your component right? How such dependencies are injected into you Component? Do you need those in your test?